# Como mudar a URL no navegador do aplicativo Microsiga Totvs

Tags: advpl

A página padrão do Microsiga Totvs tem um navegador próprio padrão, quais são as configurações para permitir ao usuário mudar a URL ?

Só aparece a página inicial do navegador padrão da máquina utilizada,

Answer (score 2):

Para se alterar o conteúdo da pagina inicial do smartclient, deverá criar um arquivo com nome mp.htm na pasta smartclient dos usuários e dentro deste arquivo realizar uma programação html para fazer a chamada para a url que o usuário deseja